# Are there global only updates in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I have a question regarding the working of a TensorFlow.

I have a function like this:

```html
def forwardPropagation(dataset, weights_l1, bias_l1, weights_l2, bias_l2, weights_out, bias_out):
    a1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(dataset, weights_l1, axes = 1) + bias_l1)
    a2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(a1, weights_l2, axes = 1) + bias_l2)
    z_out = tf.tensordot(a2, weights_out, axes = 1) + bias_out
    return z_out
```

Now I assigned:

`z_out = forwardPropagation(dataset, weights_l1, bias_l1, weights_l2, bias_l2, weights_out, bias_out)`

Also I initialised all weights and biases globally. My question is that I heard TensorFlow has a global computation graph. Does that mean that the weights and variances are getting updated globally when it run z_out and an optimiser from inside a session? Or something else is happening?

Comment: "Also I initialised all weights and biases globally.", what do you mean? "My question is that I heard TensorFlow has a global computation graph.", where? A link to the resource stating it? What do you mean by "...updated globally..."?

Comment: Also, please, provide us with a [**minimal**, **complete**, and **verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if you show us some code.

Comment: @nbro globally means outside any function...It's in a video so I cannot point it out due to the length of video...Updated globally means there is only one copy of the variable which is being updated and not some different copy being updated in the function

Comment: You can link us to the video! (If you have the exact minute, that would also be helpful).

Comment: @nbro I don't have the exact link..But isn't it common knowledge that tensorflow has a global computation graph?